# No Audio from Jack on Asus Pro60v

Tags: sound, spdif, audio-jack

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a friends old Laptop (ASUS PRO60V). Everything is running great except I cant get any audio output from the output jack.

Audio works fine through the internal speakers, but once I plug in speakers or headphones into the jack (combined SPDIF & Analog) the internal speakers are muted but there is no output on the external speakers. My guess is it is trying to output through SPDIF instead of analog...

I tried different outputs settings in the sound setting menu and also looked at alsa mixer, but couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be much apreciated!

Kernel:

```
3.0.0-14-generic
```

ASound:

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.24.
```

Codec:

```
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Realtek ALC880

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#1 <==
Codec: Conexant ID 2bfa
```

Alsa Info [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=7590b06a4745e0bdea6473579541253eb29d79bd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was provided by lidex at the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1902247):

open a terminal and type:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=z71v position_fix=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

then reboot the computer.